# How to put Media queries in javascript

Tags: javascript, media-queries

Im new into JavaScript, I'm trying to find out how to write a media query under 768px I have 3 boxes with the same height, when the other box have a long header the height of 2 boxes will follow. 
My JavaScript is working good but I have issue under 768px. I want to disable the function I made under 768px. Is there anyone who can guide me? Your help will  highly appreciated. `

```
function sameHeightCta(mediaQuery) {
    varHcta;

    if (mediaQuery.matches) {
        $('.c-cta-box .c-cta-box-headline').css('height', window.GlobalElementHight + 'px');
    } else {
        $('.c-cta-box .c-cta-box-headline').css('height', window.GlobalElementHight);
    }
}

function init() {

    var currentElementHight = window.matchmedia('(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px)');
    currentElementHight.addListener(sameHeightCta);
    sameHeightCta(GlobalElementHight);


    window.GlobalElementHight = 0;
    $('.c-cta-box .c-cta-box-headline').each(function (index) {
        var currentElementHight = $(this).height();
        if (window.GlobalElementHight < currentElementHight) {
            window.GlobalElementHight = currentElementHight;
        }
    });
    $('.c-cta-box .c-cta-box-headline').css('height', window.GlobalElementHight + 'px');
}`
```

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive and the matchmedia function on the window object is matchMedia (camel-casing).

Comment: An image of what you want would help a lot

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52291224/trigger-events-when-css-breakpoints-are-reached/52291303#52291303) that I answered might be of interest

Answer (score 0):

I would try this
`if (screen.width > 768) {  //put here the function you wanna disable on small devices}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I made to solve the problem.

```
$(window).resize(function () {

    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        $('.c-cta-box .c-cta-box-headline').css("height", "");
    } else {
        window.GlobalElementHight = 0;
        $('.c-cta-box .c-cta-box-headline').each(function (index) {
            var currentElementHight = $(this).height();
            if (window.GlobalElementHight < currentElementHight) {
                window.GlobalElementHight = currentElementHight;
            }
        });
        $('.c-cta-box .c-cta-box-headline').css('height', window.GlobalElementHight + 'px');
    }
});
```